# How to manipulate (valid / invalid) form validation on form control based on condition in Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, angular-forms

I have a form where i can update Email and Password so i created FormControl using form Group as

```
this.user= new FormGroup({
            Email: new FormControl("", [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"),
                Validators.maxLength(60)
            ]),
            ConfirmEmail: new FormControl("", [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"),
                Validators.maxLength(60)
            ]),
            Password: new FormControl("", [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,}$"),
                Validators.maxLength(60)
            ]),
            ConfirmPassword: new FormControl("", [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,}$"),
                Validators.maxLength(60)
            ])
        });
```

But Email and ConfirmEmail Section is shown only if user wants to update eventhough it is hidden using *ngIf The Form is still invalid because of email and Confirm email can we dynamically remove and add form controls

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can dynamically add and remove form controls using a dynamic reactive form.

Angular cover this in their docs in depth ... https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Essentially they use there an array of FormControl's